# Npm package working locally but not with from npm repo with npx

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package

I've created a new cli based node application and published it to npm.

When I run the package locally with:

```
npm run build
```

which just runs `rm -rf lib && tsc -b`

and then

```
npm link
npx my-package arguments
```

it is working fine.

---

But when I run directly from npm (not locally and after removing the local one)

```
npx my-package arguments
```

It gives me an import error.

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/my-package/lib/src/cli/lex.js' imported from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/my-package/lib/src/index.js
```

note sure why?

Problematic code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { command } from './cli/lex.js';
command.parse(process.argv);
```

Folder Structure

```
lib
 - src
 - - index.js
 - - cli
 - - - lex.js
```

Output of `ls -l /usr/local/lib/node_modules/my-package/lib/src/cli`

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  1893 Oct 26  1985 cli.js.map
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   402 Oct 26  1985 lex.js.map
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  2000 Oct 26  1985 parse.js.map
```

There are map files but not the actual js

[Here is the file in the project (github)](https://github.com/imanpalsingh/pg-faker/blob/main/src/index.ts) if required.

Comment: Please add all necessary details to your question. External links can break and this question becomes useless for future users. What's the result for `ls -l /usr/local/lib/node_modules/my-package/lib/src/cli`?

Comment: @jabaa  The output is  `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  1893 Oct 26  1985 cli.js.map
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   402 Oct 26  1985 lex.js.map
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  2000 Oct 26  1985 parse.js.map`

Comment: There is no `lex.js`. That's the problem. Where is the `lex.js` file?

Comment: It is there on my local project, but not  in installed one, not sure why. @jabaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging and pushing useless path versions if I found out that it was due to this in my `.gitignore`

```
*.js
```

Due to this the js files generated were not being pushed to npm and thus the error.